# Mystery System.Object.GetType() NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, casting

We experienced a crash in our program that we are now unable to reproduce. I am trying to put in some code to prevent it from happening again but I am confused over the stack trace.

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at System.Object.GetType()
   at Project.ViewModel.MainVM.<CreateCommands>b__8(Object a)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Button.OnClick()
```

-- I have cut down the stack trace as it just goes into a load of system code which is just to do with the button being clicked. --

I have managed to deduce that it is pointing to my anonymous delegate on line 8 of my CreateCommands method.

```
        this.sectionCommand = new DelegateCommand(a =>
        {
            this.OnSectionParameterChanged((Sections)a);
        }, p => this.IsSectionCommandExecutable);
```

I have seen a similar post on here but the OP was calling GetType explicitly. I am assuming that the cast calls get type, but without being able to reproduce the issue I cannot see what is null.

So my question is: For this stack trace to cause a null reference, is the 'a' variable the null object? (so I would write something like)

```
            if (a != null)
            {
                this.OnSectionParameterChanged((Sections)a);
            }
```

or is the cast from 'a' to 'sections' causing a null object? (so I should write something like)

```
            if (a is Sections)
            {
                this.OnSectionParameterChanged((Sections)a);
            }
```

As requested here is OnSectionParameterChanged

```
    private void OnSectionParameterChanged(Sections parameter)
    {
        this.SelectedSection = parameter;

        this.RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.SelectedSection);

        this.LoadSettingsPanel();
    }
```

further to that it calls a LoadSettingsPanel

```
    private void LoadSettingsPanel()
    {
        if (sectionVMs == null)
            return;

        // Get section
        SectionViewModel = sectionVMs.SingleOrDefault(s.SectionName == SelectedSection);

        this.IsSelectedSectionEnabled = this.Config.GetIsSectionEnabled(this.SelectedSection);

        this.RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.IsSelectedSectionEnabled);

        // Set advanced
        AdvancedViewModel = this.SectionViewModel;

        if (AdvancedViewModel != null)
            HasAdvanced = AdvancedViewModel.HasAdvanced;
    }
```

Comment: The more interesting question is: Why is GetType on the stack although you are not calling it? Post the body of OnSectionParameterChanged. It might have been inlined and called GetType. Also, how can GetType itself crash with a NRE? Is that a CLR bug?

Comment: did you try debugging? put a breakpoint before `this.OnSectionParameterChanged()` and see for yourself what the value of `a` is, and use the immediate window to see the value of `(Sections)a)` is

Comment: was it just a once off error that is not reproducible? it could be that the exception was a symptom  of another problem on the machine running the application.

Comment: Please show more of the stack trace.

Comment: None of your assumptions seem to apply because the exception comes from `GetType` whose call is not shown. It´s interesting where this method is called, probably within your `OnSectionParameterChanged`.

Comment: According to CoreClr, GetType is an intrinsic which throws NRE if called with a null reference (`ObjectNative::GetClass`). Normally, C# calls methods with null checking which is why I wonder how this can ever happen. We need to see OnSectionParameterChanged.

Comment: Try casting "a" before you pass it into "OnSectionParameterChanged". As in: var castA = a as Sections. Put a breakpoint there and see what you have.

Comment: @usr (and everyone else) I have updated the post now with the new code.

Comment: I am wondering whether my assumption that it is the anonymous delegate on the 8th line was incorrect. Has anyone else seen that type of stack trace before? at Project.ViewModel.MainVM.<CreateCommands>b__8(Object a)

Comment: What does `RaisePropertyChanged()` look like?

Comment: @CodeCaster It takes in the property and basically gets the name from it and then passes that into a PropertyChanged method don't ask why it didn't just use the property changed method in the first place It is code from a different team that no longer work here.

Comment: The stack trace should have line numbers. If this is a production trace put PDBs into production. Release mode can produce PDBs as well. Decompile the assembly to make sure that `b__8` is what you expect.

Comment: @usr I was very confused when I didn't see line numbers. This was from an installed version from a tester. Is there anyway to get the real stack trace from the testers machine?

Comment: @Keith _"It takes in the property and basically gets the name from it"_ - yeah, so it uses reflection, which may call a `GetType()` somewhere. Given the limited information you're giving, I suspect that method to be the culprit. Show the source, or if you don't have it, decompile it.

Comment: @CodeCaster I actually just realised that the team before have created an extension method called GetMemberInfo() which returns a MemberInfo and that is the method it is using the get the name to pass into the property changed method. It doesn't call any methods it just casts the expression to various different variabled to eventually get the MemberInfo. I can post the code if you think it will help but I don't want to bloat the post so that it becomes unhelpful.

Comment: Is `RaisePropertyChanged()` in the call stack? Then it's relevant.

Comment: @usr I have just checked using IlDasm and it looks like <CreateCommands>b__8 is actually the anonymous delegate to enable the section which does call GetType() on SectionViewModel. I am guessing something got its wires crossed and got confused but at least now I know where to put the null check. Thanks for all your help. I read on a different website that the __8 was the line number, which is clearly wrong.

Comment: @CodeCaster no it isn't. The call stack was pretty useless, it just confused me because I had never seen anything like it and I had read somewhere that __8 meant that it was the 8th line in the method which matched up with the anonymous delegate I shared. clearly this was wrong and I have now found (I hope) the GetType() call which it is complaining about.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The problem that I had described was actually not the real problem. I read on a different site that the `< CreateCommands >b__8` part of the stack trace meant that the issue was on line 8 of the `CreateCommands` method. This lined up exactly with an anonymous delegate and I could see how it matched the behaviour in the bug report.

I actually found the solution to my problem by using IL Dasm (which can be found in

> \Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin

and opened the EXE which was run and found what the .net thought `b__8` actually was. This turned out to be another anonymous delegate which was explicitly calling `.GetType()` so the problem was actually really easy once I found out what `b__8` actually meant.